# Declaring Symfony Form options (Sym 2.8/3.0)

Tags: symfony-forms, symfony, symfony-2.8

I am looking for the best method for creating/adding dynamic options in a form. By options, I mean things like choice value pairs, or maybe even default values. I can see at least three options:

1) add the options to the `$options` array when adding the form type. For this, it appears that I must first declare a default value and then add them in the `add` method and in the controller:

controller:

```
    $choices = [];
    foreach ($pages as $page) {
        $choices[$page->getId()] = $page->getTitle();
    }
    $options = ['pages' => $choices];
    $form = $this->createForm('MyBundle\Form\Type\PageType', $data, $options);
```

FormType:

```
class PageType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('pid', 'Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\ChoiceType', [
                'choices' => $options['pages'],
                'label' => __('Page')
            ]);
    }
...
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'pages' => []
        ]);
    }
}
```

2) If the values are not dependent on controller values, it seems I could create them in the `OptionsResolver` (assuming access to the source data)

FormType:

```
class PageType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('pid', 'Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\ChoiceType', [
                'choices' => $options['pages'],
                'label' => __('Page')
            ]);
    }
...
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $choices = [];
        $pages = $this->getPages();
        foreach ($pages as $page) {
            $choices[$page->getId()] = $page->getTitle();
        }

        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'pages' => $choices
        ]);
    }
```

3) Finally, I can also add in the `buildForm` method (again assuming access to source data):

FormType:

```
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $choices = [];
        $pages = $this->getPages();
        foreach ($pages as $page) {
            $choices[$page->getId()] = $page->getTitle();
        }

        $builder
            ->add('pid', 'Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\ChoiceType', [
                'choices' => $choices,
                'label' => __('Page')
            ]);
    }
```

Obviously, there is the most flexibility in the first option, but If I do not require that flexibility, or do not want to manage the options in the controller for some reason, does it make more sense to do the work in the `buildForm` or `configureOptions` methods?

Answer (score 2):

If you require flexibility you can't use solution 3. But if you want to avoid flexibility, solution 3 is the best.

Solution 1 and 2 are OK, it really depend of what you need :

- If you use your form in several actions with different choices: use solution 1, but add a requirement on this option to prevent the form to be called without choices
- If your choices are often the same, but you want to override them only sometimes: chose solution 2

Personally I prefer the solution 1, because it's always better if your form relies on the less possible external objects (`$this->pages` in your example).

Regards

Comment: I agree also that solution 1 is optimal, 3 is easiest but requires external dependencies (and therefore likely a service definition) which isn't great since the form is only used very occasionally and not reused in other instances.

Answer (score 1):

If you work with Doctrine Entities, you should use this:

```php
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Form\Type\EntityType;
// ...

$builder->add('pid', EntityType::class, array(
    'class' => 'AppBundle:Page',
    'choice_label' => 'title',
));
```

For working with another type of objects this one:

```php
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\ChoiceType;
use AppBundle\Entity\Page;
// ...

$builder->add('pid', ChoiceType::class, [
    'choices' => [
        new Page('Page 1'),
        new Page('Page 2'),
        new Page('Page 3'),
        new Page('Page 4'),
    ],
    'choices_as_values' => true,
    'choice_label' => function($page, $key, $index) {
        /** @var Page $page */
        return $page->getTitle();
    }
]);
```

More information you can read in [blog post here](http://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-2-7-choice-form-type-refactorization).

Comment: That is a good idea to consider but I was posturing a generic example that may or may not use entities as the data source.